# Multiple Constructors

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have a class called ErrorItem that have multiple construtors. Is it possible to call another constructor inside of the constructor to manage default values?

Example:

```
    CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC ErrorItem():
        ErrorItem("", "", "", -1, "", "").
    END CONSTRUCTOR.

    CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC ErrorItem(
         ItemNo AS CHARACTER
        ,UpcCode AS CHARACTER
        ,CustomerPo AS CHARACTER
        ,ColumnId AS INTEGER
        ,Description AS CHARACTER):
        ErrorItem(ItemNo, UpcCode, CustomerPo, ColumnId, Description, "").
    END CONSTRUCTOR.

    CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC ErrorItem(
         ItemNo AS CHARACTER
        ,UpcCode AS CHARACTER
        ,CustomerPo AS CHARACTER
        ,ColumnId AS INTEGER
        ,Description AS CHARACTER
        ,Detail AS CHARACTER
    ):        
        ASSIGN
            THIS-OBJECT:ItemNo = ItemNo
            THIS-OBJECT:UpcCode = UpcCode
            THIS-OBJECT:CustomerPo = CustomerPo
            THIS-OBJECT:ColumnId = ColumnId
            THIS-OBJECT:Description = Description
            THIS-OBJECT:Detail = Detail
        .
    END CONSTRUCTOR.
```

Thank you!
Sebastien

Comment: With this code, I get the compiler error: Constructors cannot be called directly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - the format is:

```
CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC ErrorItem(variable list): 
THIS-OBJECT(local variable list).

/* Stuff */
END CONSTRUCTOR.
```

Also the "THIS-OBJECT" call has to be the first statement in the constructor.